# HTML to PDF with inline SVG by using Laravel

Tags: laravel-7

I have an HTML that contains inline SVG data. I want to convert that HTML file into the PDF file. I have tried 2 packages TCPDF and DOMPDF to convert HTML into PDF. These packages are not displaying SVG content in the converted PDF files.Here is my HTML content

```
    <div style="position: relative;"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1659/7869/products/TEAM-TAKEDOWN-STREAMLINE-WHITE.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: auto;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 216px; left: 194px;width: 225px;height: 330px;overflow: hidden;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="225" height="330" viewBox="0 0 225 330" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
</defs>
<g transform="matrix(0.5 0 0 0.5 112.5 165)"  >
    <image style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  xlink:href="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/assets/no-image-100-c91dd4bdb56513f2cbf4fc15436ca35e9d4ecd014546c8d421b1aece861dfecf_small.gif" x="-50" y="-50" width="100" height="100"></image>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(0.5 0 0 0.5 112.5 165)"  >
    <image style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  xlink:href="https://accessibilityplus.ca/storage/images/1597153275_Asset%201%20copy%202.png" x="-215.5" y="-244.5" width="431" height="489"></image>
</g>
<g transform="matrix(0.5 0 0 0.5 112.5 165)"  >
    <image style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-dashoffset: 0; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;"  xlink:href="https://accessibilityplus.ca/storage/images/1595491407_1592358037_design.png" x="-200" y="-200" width="400" height="400"></image>
</g>
</svg></div></div>
```

Here is my current output: http://prntscr.com/u5jcc3.

Here is the expected output: http://prntscr.com/u5jd4s.

Comment: try adding `fill="#000000"` after `viewBox` in svg declaration

Comment: see this issue https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1612